# Display emoji object to text field or textarea in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

I'm building my app with [`emoji-mart`](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart) lib.

I have text input like this:

```
<FormGroup>
  {emoji}

  <EmojiMartPicker
    set='emojione'
    onSelect={(emoji) => console.log(emoji)}
    onChange={this.onChange}
  >
    <Input
      type="text"
      name="emotion"
      bsSize="sm"
      autoComplete="off"
      value={report.emotion.colons}
      onChange={this.onHandleFormChange}
      required
    />
  </EmojiMartPicker>
</FormGroup>
```

Now, I wanna display Emoji Object to text input. In `value` attribute. I want to display emoji, not value text.

How can we do that?

See my detail problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/646xom9y1z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found that just only add `native` props to solved my problem.

Like this:

`value={report.emotion.native}`

That's it..

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem take a look.

```
<div className="chatemoji">
          <ButtonToolbar >
            <div onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
              {/* <EmojiField
                name="textarea"
                 onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                fieldType="input"
              /> */}

               <EmojiField name="my-textarea" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} fieldType="input" />

            </div>
          </ButtonToolbar>
          </div>
```

In onChange you have to call this code

```
onChange(e,value) { 
    this.state.data += value;
    this.setState({ data: this.state.data });
   }
```